# BLE write not work when it work some time

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My English not good

I use Google sample BLEGATT

Now I add some code so I can get notification when BLE change data

When notification work I will send data.

(50ms BLE give me data so I send also 50ms)

It will work some time

Finally it will not send but receiver work ok

How to fix it?

Comment: It'd be useful for you to share your existing code for this functionality and provide logs so we can see how you know for certain the receiver is working fine but it is unable to send data.

Comment: Ok now I use cellphone my work computer no internet so I will post code tomorrow

Comment: I take a picture but my level can't post picture

Comment: Please don't take a picture. It's easier for others to look at your code if you paste it within the question. It also means it's easier for people to copy your code to replicate your issue.